# Xperia U ST25i (Android 2.3.7 - Gingerbread) - Where is Developer Options?

Tags: settings, sony-xperia-u

There is some way to active developer options in 2.3.7? When I bought my Xperia U, they came with developer options and 2.3.7 android. How it works? I tried press 7 times on build number and those thing, but nothing worked, someone can help me, PLEASE? I don't want to use ICS, JB or some different android.

Thank you, guys! ﻿

Comment: The tapping on build number 7 times is *specific* to JB and later.

Comment: Yeah, I heard about it. But what I'm supposed to do in GB?

Comment: You stated "When I bought my Xperia U, they came with developer options" so what's the problem?

Comment: I update my mobile to ICS after buy my celphone, after that I install GB again through FlashTool and I lost developer options.

Comment: Did u check in `Settings` It is usually above the `about phone`